# Pipe Network: Computing the inflows for systems with multiple reservoir (input source)

Tags: algorithm, pipe-network

Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, we have the following Y Shape water pipe network:

[image]

`S1` and `S2` are the reservoirs ( input source), `Sout` is the water demand where water is drawn out for commercial use or whatever use. We know the height of the reservoirs at `S1` and `S2` relative to the ground and we also know the height of the `Sout`.

All `S1`, `S2` and `Sout` are in`m^3/s`.

For the pipe, we know for each pipe their corresponding diameter `d`, length `L`, roughness coefficient `C`.

My question is, given the above information, is there anyway we can uniquely compute `S1` and `S2` for the Y shape network above? From what I know, we have one equation but two unknowns ( the conservation of source):

`Sout=S1+S2`

But this is not sufficient for us to uniquely determine `S1` and `S2` unless we have other equations here. I think the height of the nodes are also playing a role in the solution, but I just don't know how it can be done. Any ideas?

On a side note, if our water pipe network is a loop, we can use the [hazen william formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazen%E2%80%93Williams_equation) and [hardy cross method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_Cross_method) to compute the head loss. This means that whatever that is required to be known about the pipe is already known, as long as they are used in hazen william formula and hardy cross method.

Comment: Appears to be a math question and not related to GIS.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I don't think this is a "math" question ( for it certainly involves geophysics)

Comment: What are these drains? Are they pixels in a raster? You have told us nothing about the dataset, an image would be nice, hence my thought that you had abstract it away to a math question.

Comment: @Hornbydd, The flow of the drain shall be determined by Manning Formula. There is no raster or advanced dataset involved.

Comment: Which tool are you using to do the flow-direction map? the [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass75/manuals/r.watershed.html) has the flag -s to cope with it: SFD: single flow direction, MFD: multiple flow direction

Comment: It seems you need some hydraulic calculations, are your drians open conduits or pipes? why not hec-ras? swmm? Who said hydraulic problems do not involve "advanced dataset"?

Comment: @Marco, you have any section in swmm that would address my needs?

Comment: SMWW handles drainage systems, at each node it solves this problem if there are two or more pipes going out from a node. I can get very few from your presentation of the problem, but also I guess you are not familiar with the discipline or SWMM. Could you make a sketch of your problem and say why you see it as a GIS problem?

Comment: @Marco, I've updated with a sketch

Comment: @gisnside, yes, it is a dupe, so I've closed it as such ( so dupes aren't necessarily useless after all!)

Comment: Compute pipes capacity, using their slopes, roughness etc. Split flow pro rata. Express as fractions. This is how I do it anyway.

Comment: @FelixIP, I know that I have how to compute pipe capacity ( via manning formula and such), but how to split flow? You mention "split flow pro rata", and according to what criterion it should be carried out? The pipe size ratio, or something else?

Comment: Pro rata of capacities.

Comment: @FelixIP, on what grounds do you think that pro rata of capacities is the correct way of distributing the flow?

Comment: Because they work this way, when they are full and b) this is pragmatic approach, unless you are desperate to dive into hydraulic modeling rightly mentioned in solution below.

Comment: @FelixIP, not sure whether you are right on "they work this way, when they are full" ( any links or any papers?), but there is a reason I don't quite believe in it, are you sure that the differential gradients between two outstreams/instreams are not playing a role at all?

Comment: They are part of capacity calculation, mate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic hydraulic problem. It varies a lot if it is a pressurized system or not. I would hardly tag it as `hydrology`, it has almost nothing to do with it, but I consider it a relevant GIS topic.

For pressurized complex network systems there the EPANET, an "*Application for Modeling Drinking Water Distribution Systems*" [link](https://www.epa.gov/water-research/epanet)

In case of free flow systems, there is SWMM, an "application that helps predict the quantity and quality of runoff within urban areas" [link](https://www.epa.gov/water-research/storm-water-management-model-swmm)

For both software there are some links to GIS, but that is another very wide question.

Comment: Marco, is it possible to show the corresponding SWMM or EPANET section that directly answers my question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_network_analysis

Comment: The EPANET User's manual has everything [link](http://nepis.epa.gov/Adobe/PDF/P1007WWU.pdf) but I thing it is not a good starting point to study hydraulics

Comment: Marco, you said that you would hardly tag it as `hydrology`, do you have a more appropriate tag?

Comment: I would tag it as `hydraulic` or `pipe network`

Comment: Tag added @Marco